# How to exit loop with "keyword"

Tags: vb.net

Here's my code:

```
Dim n As String, upper As String, lower As String

    Label2.Text = "EXIT"
    Label3.Text = "exit"

    upper = Label2.Text
    Label2.Text = upper.ToUpper

    lower = Label3.Text
    Label3.Text = lower.ToLower

    Do
        Label1.Text = InputBox(" Enter a word. If you would like to quit, type: EXIT in the inputbox")
        n = Label1.Text
        Label1.Text = n.Length
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text & " letters"
    Loop Until n = ""
    Label1.Visible = False
    MsgBox(" Invalid value!")
    End

    Do
        Label1.Text = InputBox(" Enter a word. If you would like to quit, type: EXIT in the inputbox")
        n = Label1.Text
        Label1.Text = n.Length
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text & " letters"
    Loop Until upper = Label2.Text
    Label1.Visible = False
    MsgBox(" You have exited the program!")
    End

    Do
        Label1.Text = InputBox(" Enter a word. If you would like to quit, type: EXIT in the inputbox")
        n = Label1.Text
        Label1.Text = n.Length
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text & " letters"
    Loop Until lower = Label3.Text
    Label1.Visible = False
    MsgBox(" You have exited the program!")
    End
```

The issue I'm having with this program is when I run it and press the cancel button or the X button to exit, it executes correctly with the loop. But with the other 2 loops, when I type in "exit" or "EXIT" in uppercase or lowercase, it just displays how many characters are in the word instead of ending the program.

Comment: Both your `upper` and `lower` variables are only set once _before_ all of the loops. Also, this doesn't look like VBA code. You're probably using VB.NET.

Comment: It's a little hard to see exactly what you're doing here so maybe you need to explain it a little better.  As it stands, firstly I would ask what debugging have you done?  Inspecting you program state at each point may give you the answer.  Next thing, are you sure "End" is the correct thing to hit after each of you loops?  Assuming this is a method in a winforms app, I suspect that's not really what you want to happen

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have worked on it after this post was created and eventually fixed it through some trial and error. It was a small mistake I made with the loops, it now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer is missing, I state that the String "Label3" is not part of the InputBox String defaultValue. The "Label1" Text is used and not changed to be saved to "Label2" or "Label3".

The Do Statement seems to iterate with integer datatypes. An sample is to be found on a page for [do loop statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/do-loop-statement).
The negotiation for retriving examples leads to choose either a character or a number. And until a boolean statement is not recognized redirect text like above

> Loop Until n = ""

is the easy part.

A newline for an integer value is not necessary a boolean value. The integer can be a boolean value. If integers are dissected until they can be used for a boolean logic the possibiltiy can be used for iterations.

So a string like Text "Label1" is not an obvious boolean value.

I can not sample the question with an answer that takes the whole process apart, but post a part that exits the loop linking the string to a boolean value.

```
    Public Class Form1        
        Private myValue As Object
        ReadOnly AntiPanel As New Label
        Private boolenValueTools As Boolean
    
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    
            Dim message, title, defaultValue As String
            ' Set prompt.
            message = " Enter a word. If you would like to quit, type: EXIT in the inputbox"
            ' Set title.
            title = "InputBox Demo"
            defaultValue = "1"   ' Set default value.
    
            '' Display dialog box at position 100, 100.
            'myValue = InputBox(message, title, defaultValue, 100, 100)
            '' If user has clicked Cancel, set myValue to defaultValue
            'If myValue Is "" Then myValue = defaultValue
    
            ' Display message, title, and default value.
            Do
                myValue = InputBox(message, title, defaultValue)
                If myValue = "EXIT" Then boolenValueTools = True
            Loop Until boolenValueTools = True
            ' If user has clicked Cancel, set myValue to defaultValue
            If myValue Is "" Then myValue = defaultValue
    
            Me.Controls.Add(AntiPanel)
            With AntiPanel
                .AutoSize = True
                .BackColor = Color.Transparent
                .Location = New Point(100, 100)
                .Font = New Font("Consolas", 55.75, FontStyle.Regular)
                .Text = myValue 'in my case also known as NotNamedInputBoxTextString
            End With
        End Sub
    End Class
```